# C Delete last character in string

Tags: c, string, character, strtok

I want to delete last character in string
first, i use strtok function
My Input is : `"Hello World Yaho"`
I use `" "` as my delimeter

My expectation is this

```
Hell
Worl
Yah
```

But the actual output is this

```
Hello
Worl
Yaho
```

How can I solve this problem? I can't understand this output

this is my code

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
   char *string;
   char *ptr;
   string = (char*)malloc(100);

   puts("Input a String");
   fgets(string,100,stdin);

   printf("Before calling a function: %s]n", string);

   ptr = strtok(string," ");

   printf("%s\n", ptr);

   while(ptr=strtok(NULL, " "))
   {
      ptr[strlen(ptr)-1]=0;
      printf("%s\n", ptr);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That `strtok` in the while-expression should be the last statement in the loop body, and the while expression should simply check `ptr != NULL`

Comment: http://ideone.com/6u5odn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program deletes the last character of every word.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    char *string;
    char *ptr;
    string = (char*)malloc(100);
    puts("Input a String");
    fgets(string,100,stdin);
    printf("Before calling a function: %s\n", string);
    string[strlen(string)-1]=0;
    ptr = strtok(string," ");
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    while(ptr){
        ptr[strlen(ptr)-1]=0;
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(0, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You must remember to

1. Trim the string from trailing newline
2. Use strtok properly

**Test**

```
Input a String
Hello World Yaho
Before calling a function: Hello World Yaho

Hello
Hell
Worl
Yah
```

Comment: Careful. There are unchecked failure points that could lead to *undefined behavior*. Checking for success of `fgets` before entertaining the rest of the program is pretty critical.

Comment: `fgets()` may return a buffer without a newline in some cases: if the file does not contain one at the end or if the line is longer than the buffer can accomodate. A safer way to trim the line feed from the buffer filled by `fgets` is `string[p(strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is best solved by splitting it in 2 phases: parsing the phrase into words on one hand, with `strtok` if you wish, and printing the words with their last character omitted in a separate function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void print_truncated_word(const char *ptr) {
    int len = strlen(ptr);
    if (len > 0) len -= 1;
    printf("%.*s", len, ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    char buf[128];
    char *ptr;

    puts("Input a string: ");
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
        /* premature end of file */
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Before calling a function: %s\n", string);

    ptr = strtok(string, " \n");
    while (ptr) {
        print_truncated_word(ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `print_truncated_word` function does not modify the buffer. Side effects on input arguments should be avoided, unless they are the explicit goal of the function.  `strtok` is ill behaved to this regard, among other shortcomings such as its hidden state that prevents nested use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have to study about strtok function, more! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you kept the delm as space it will create separate tokens for space separated words in your string and c-style strings contain their last characters as '\0' i.e null character so it deletes that character and not your last character in the text.

check this out
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html

> it turns out that C-style strings are always terminated with a null character, literally a '\0' character (with the value of 0),